# How to open up mp3's, with spacing in their name, from the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-8, cmd, command, mp3

I am using `start` in the commandline to play a `.mp3` sound, like this:

```
c:\users\thisuser\desktop>start thissong.mp3
```

and it starts the song called `thissong`. But when I try the same with a song called `this song` with a space in the letter, it wont start.

Ive tried many things like puttin in diffrent symbols (`/`, `%`, `%20`, `_` and so on) instead of the space, still it wont start the song. I even tried putting the whole name inside of `""` like `"this song.mp3"`, instead of starting the song, it opens up a new `cmd`.

How can I start a track with a space in their name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c:\users\thisuser\desktop>start "this song.mp3"` should work.
If not, it seems to be a `start` command's problem. Spaces in filename or path are usually fixing by putting them in quotes.

Comment: Ive tried that. It only opens up a new cmd instead of starting the .mp3 file.

Comment: It seems to be a `start` command's problem. Spaces in filename or path are usually fixing by putting them in quotes.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the explanation there, and use the example given in the OP's question.

Comment: This method works, but just not with `start`, as you said its probably a start problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the file name in quotes `"`.

Comment: Ive tried that. It only opens up a new cmd instead of starting the .mp3 file.